# Error with RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using Code::blocks to write a program that changes the registry, but when I call

```
RegOpenKeyEx (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
              "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\RunOnce", 
               0, 
               KEY_ALL_ACCES | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, 
               &key);
```

codeblocks return

> `KEY_WOW64_64KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)

I had add `#include <windows.h>` but it still doesn't work.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to define a Windows target version of XP or greater to have access to this. You are probably targeting Windows 2000.

In targetver.h (or wherever you define `_WIN32_WINNT`) you need this:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 //targets XP or later
```