# Error with RegOpenKeyEx()

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, registry, windows-7-x64

I'm using Qt with mingw to write a program that changes the registry, but when I call :

```
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
             "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\DefaultProductKey",
             0,
             KEY_ALL_ACCESS|KEY_WOW64_64KEY,
             &key);
```

Qt return :

```
`KEY_WOW64_64KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I had add `"#include <windows.h>"` but it still doesn't work.

I've find this post [Error with RegOpenKeyEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247862/error-with-regopenkeyex?answertab=votes#tab-top), it's the same probleme than me, and the answer looks good.
But i'm not using windows xp i'm using 7(64bits).
So I trided to put in targetver.h :

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7
#define _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 (0x0601)
#endif  /* _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7 */
```

And it's still doesn't work ... :(

What can i do ? :(

Thanks :)

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the `_WIN32_WINNT` (not _WIN32_WINNT_WIN7) before including the `windows.h` header:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT (0x0601)
#endif  /* _WIN32_WINNT */

#include <windows.h>
```