# Qt 5 + MSVC2013 static external lib LNK2001 Windows API

Tags: c++, qt, lnk2001, msvc12

I've got following scenario:

- Library that uses some Windows functions like RegOpenKeyExA aso (created and compiled with Visual Studio 2013 /MD)
- Small console application created in VS2013 that uses the library (static linked; /MD). Building the console app works fine
- Small Qt5 Gui app that uses the lib as well (static linked; Qt 5.3.1 with MSVC2013)

When I build the Qt app in Qt Creator I get following output:

```
10:39:52: The process "D:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\5.3\msvc2013\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
10:39:52: Starting: "D:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    D:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:release\TEST_app_Qt.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:release\TEST_app_Qt.exe @C:\Users\gortner\AppData\Local\Temp\TEST_app_Qt.exe.12772.63.jom
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptAcquireContextW@20
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptSetKeyParam@16
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegSetValueExA@24
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegQueryValueExA@24
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptReleaseContext@8
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyExA@20
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptImportKey@24
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegDeleteValueA@8
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptDestroyKey@4
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetUserNameA@8
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptDecrypt@24
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__SHGetFolderPathA@20
MyLib.lib(MyLib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4
release\TEST_app_Qt.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 13 unresolved externals
jom: D:\Development\build-TEST_app_Qt-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\Makefile.Release [release\TEST_app_Qt.exe] Error 1120
jom: D:\Development\build-TEST_app_Qt-Desktop_Qt_5_3_MSVC2013_32bit-Release\Makefile [release] Error 2
10:39:52: The process "D:\Qt\Qt5.3.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TEST_app_Qt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.3 MSVC2013 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
10:39:52: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

My .pro file:

```
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-09-01T11:10:50
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TEST_app_Qt
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
    mymath.cpp \
    stdafx.cpp

 HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
     mymath.h \
     targetver.h \
     stdafx.h

FORMS    += \
    mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/inc
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/inc

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/ -lMyLib

#win32: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/lib/MyLib.lib

QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -MT
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD
```

As mentioned above. When I use the lib in a VS project it works fine but in Qt i have troubles

Comment: Hope this link solve it 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528099/error-with-regopenkeyex

Comment: Might help u

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528099/error-with-regopenkeyex

LIBS += advapi32.lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look up the listed missing symbols in MSDN you will find that they are in Advapi32.lib. That import lib is not listed in the LIBS in your .pro file. Try adding the following:

```
win32: LIBS += Advapi32.lib
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. With this and some additional changes (removed #include "stdafx.h") I got it working!