# What is _WIN32_WINNT and how does it work?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

**EDIT 2:** Ok so I changed to Orwell DevC++ which contains the "winnt.h" that contains *#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0x0100* but it still is not working. *(Refer to EDIT 1:)*

**EDIT 1:** I looked into the "winnt.h" which came along the CodeBlock and DevC++ and the DevC++'s is missing the following lines:

```
#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0502)
#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY 0x0100
#define KEY_WOW64_32KEY 0x0200
#endif
```

And putting the above code in the wint.h of DevC++ doesn't work.

---

**Original Post:**
I have a 32bit application (developing in DevC++ and Windows 7 64bit) which reads a 64bit app's registry as one of its task, so I am trying to use "KEY_WOW64_64KEY" flag in RegOpenKeyEx, and found few posts regarding how to use it with _WIN32_WINNT : [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528099/error-with-regopenkeyex) and [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247862/error-with-regopenkeyex)

It worked like charm when I used it in a CodeBlock Project(a test project) but the same code is not working with DevC++, I can't port it to codeblock now since codeblock presents other problems.

How do I make it work with DevC++ ?

Thanks

Comment: For question 1: did you try plugging _WIN32_WINNT in google, which leads straight to the relevant Microsoft documentation?

Comment: Can you get DevC++ to build against the [standard Windows platform SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx)? Then it should just work. Can you give us more information about it not working in DevC++?

Comment: @Rup Don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Rup As far about it not working in DevC++, there is nothing much to say, even if I put the #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601 it still gives the error "KEY_WOW64_64KEY" undeclared, even though the same code works in CodeBlock.

Comment: I mean where are the header files - the .h files - that you're compiling against coming from when you're building with DevC++? You should look in those files, probably one called winnt.h, for the KEY_WOW64_64KEY definition and see what conditionals are surrounding it. If it's not there at all then you need a new version of the windows headers. Of course if it's just the one value you need you can copy the definition into your own code: `#define KEY_WOW64_64KEY (0x0100)`. But you should try and get the header versions working too.

Comment: @Rup Please see the EDIT 1: and EDIT 2: above.

Comment: Do you have any pre-compiled header mechanism you need to rebuild with the modified headers? If not, the simplest change now would be to replace `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` in your `RegOpenKeyEx` call with `0x100`.

Comment: @Rup looks like I will have to go with 0x100 way. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

It defines the version of the windows header files to use.  It must be declared before you `#include <Windows.h>`.

There are a few other similar variables you should probably set if you're going to modify it:

[MSDN Using Windows Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. `_WIN32_WINNT` is a preprocessor token, which is replaced by `(0x0601)` wherever `_WIN32_WINNT` is used. The preprocessor just scans the whole file and replaces `_WIN32_WINNT` with `(0x0601)` everywhere it is found.

Chances are, there could be `ifdef` preprocessor guards that will enable/disable a preprocessor constant. Like:

```
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
#define KEY32 32
#endif
```

There, `KEY32` will only be defined **IF** `_WIN32_WINNT` is defined.

1. It already works with DevC++.

Comment: *Chances are, there could be ifdef preprocessor guards that will enable/disable a preprocessor constant*.  I don't think that's the case, since same code works with CodeBlock.