# 'GetProcessIdOfThread': identifier not found

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

Here is my codes in **stdafx.h** :

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0502

#include "winsock2.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Iphlpapi.h"
#include <psapi.h>
#include "Ntsecapi.h"
#include "txdtc.h"
#include "xolehlp.h" 
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

As you see i have included "windows.h"

And here is main codes :

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
...
if (hThread && dwRpcssPid == GetProcessIdOfThread(hThread))   
...
```

My errors are :

> 'GetProcessIdOfThread': identifier not found
>
> IntelliSense: identifier "GetProcessIdOfThread" is undefined

How can i fix these errors?

Comment: Is it *just* an IntelliSense error? If so then you can disregard it. Other than that, you don't happen to have a file named `windows.h` in the same directory as your `stdafx.h`, do you? Alternatively, does adding `#include <Windows.h>` in *the same file* as `GetProcessIdOfThread()` remove the error?

Comment: so sorry, please review my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is not available with `_WIN32_WINNT` values less than `0x0600` AKA `_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA`. If you change your code this way, you will get it working:

```
//#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0502
#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0600
```

The function is available since Vista, to target Vista+ you should have this value defined respectively.

To target latest versions of API with current SDK, you can simply include SDKDDKVer.h and those values will be defined for you/

```
//#define _WIN32_WINNT  0x0502
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

See also:

- [What is _WIN32_WINNT and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111799/what-is-win32-winnt-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thanks for all answers, but this one solved my problem.

Comment: R how can i chat with you?

Comment: @MoonLight: There is no chat, but you can find email address on website in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

[`GetProcessIdOfThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s platform requirements states:

> Windows Vista [desktop apps only]
>
> Windows Server 2003 [desktop apps only]

And the header requirements states:

> Processthreadsapi.h on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012

So:

1. Make sure your windows SDK is up-to-date
2. Make sure you have specified your [platform requirements properly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
3. Make sure you're including the right header file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows 8 you need to include : Processthreadsapi.h

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) references in the header section.

Comment: I am using windows 7 - i've added this line : #include "Processthreadsapi.h" but that error still is there!!!

Comment: I am using windows 8 that being said, I could not reproduce your problem.
What I could suggest is to close visual studio, delete the .sdf (which is the intellisense) and see if this help. You could also try to click Go To Definition to see if the linker is fine. This might just be an intellisense bug.